# Protected Tiff File Viewer Suggestions

Tags: tiff, documentviewer, image-viewer

In a web app we are building in ASP .NET, there is a requirement to allow users to view TIFF image files but not to have the ability to print, save or copy these documents. We understand users may be able to print screen, and thus no solution will be 100% foolproof.

Can anyone suggest some TIFF file viewers which can allow us to prevent users from saving, copying or printing these document and also will integrate with an ASP .NET application?

Thanks a million! 
- Cian

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have three options:

1. embed TIFF images in Silverlight application
2. embed TIFF images in Flash/Flex/Air application
3. break each TIFF image into pieces and show them using HTML/CSS

Last option is not very practical one, though.

If you decide to use Silverlight for showing TIFF images, then you may want to look at [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) (free, open-source, commercial-friendly license). LibTiff.Net supports Silverlight and it's source code package contains Silverlight Test Application that displays Tiff images.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: Thanks Bobrovsky, I will take a look at these! In the mean time, all other suggestions are welcome! :D